# Error connecting to URL

Tags: flash, web-services, actionscript-3, soap

I am trying to connect to this service from my pc.

https://www.epithimies.gr/Consumers/Registration/Proximity.Pulse.Consumers.Registration/Application/WebServiceDescriptors/Registration/GreeceSecured.xml

using the flex Webservice libs but I get this:

> Error opening URL 'https://www.epithimies.gr/Consumers/Registration/Proximity.Pulse.Consumers.Registration/Application/RegistrationWebService.asmx'

Is that because the service is under HTTPS?

Thanks in advance

**EDIT**

After some research I found that the service send a 500 error and thus flash cannot get the full server response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your app is loaded from insecure location (http, not https), then you are not alowed to load anything from https, unless the service in question has configured crossdomain policy to allow such interaction.

**EDIT** My bad, it's not the case. They've set 'secure' attribute to 'false'.

epithimies.gr has the following policy https://www.epithimies.gr/crossdomain.xml

```
<cross-domain-policy>
    <site-control permitted-cross-domain-policies="all"/>
    <allow-http-request-headers-from domain="*" headers="*" secure="false"/>
    <allow-access-from domain="*" secure="false"/>
</cross-domain-policy>
```

Try loading data from that service with common URLLoader and see what exactly error message is saying.

Answer (score 0):

> Error opening URL
>   'https://www.epithimies.gr/Consumers/Registration/Proximity.Pulse.Consumers.Registration/Application/RegistrationWebService.asmx'
>   
>   Just like it says.
>   It cannot find the url.
>   You didn't post any code at all so I will assume are adding something dynamically to this URL causing it to fail. Where you think you are hitting this posted URL but you are not.
>   
>   Verify the URL is being called.
>   Use FireFox and install HTTPFox and use that to determine if the URL is being requested at all.